# sql server 2008 - calculated and ordered list needs to return only 2 entries per supplier

Tags: sql, rank, formatting

I have a dataset like below, but longer. I want to ensure I am picking the 'fleet_id' in terms of their 'StarDriver' value overall, but I want to return only two results for each 'supplier_id' and return a max of 20 in total.

(I'm sorry I didnt work out how to copy the below in proper formatting, couldn't find from toolbar above and google results were about copying data; would also be grateful if someone would point out how)

```
fleet_id    supplier_id Ratings Driver  Punctuality Car StarDriver

19442   151 10  5   5   5   5
19634   151 11  5   5   5   5
19437   151 12  5   5   5   5
12832   10  14  5   4.92857142857143    5   4.97619047619048
12217   111 10  5   5   4.9 4.96666666666667
21135   158 19  5   4.89473684210526    5   4.96491228070175
19436   151 14  4.85714285714286    5   5   4.95238095238095
12239   111 12  4.91666666666667    5   4.91666666666667    4.94444444444445
10520   92  12  4.91666666666667    5   4.91666666666667    4.94444444444445
19997   151 12  5   5   4.83333333333333    4.94444444444444
```

Comment: Oh Lord! - table came out worse then I thought; trying to fix

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what output you would want from the table you posted?

Answer (score 0):

To limit to the top 2 for each supplier, use `row_number()`.  This will enumerate the rows and you can choose just two with `where seqnum <= 2`.

The rest of the query is just selecting 20 rows based on a field:

```
select top 20 t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by supplier order by StarDriver desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
order by StarDriver;
```